# How to slow side panel row-offcanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap side panel appears when screen is less than `768px`. My panel comes very quickly and I want to make it to appear slowly. Could you give me any hint  about the missing part in my `jquery` code?

HTML markup:

```
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>              
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- main area -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <h1>Shrink Width to Collapse Sidebar</h1>
 </div></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] of your existing animation? Add bootstrap CSS/js and any additional resources it might need, until it exhibits the current behavior.